# Decorator isn't returning the object to the class methods in Python

Tags: python, class, flask, decorator

So I'm trying to return a object from a decorator to a method of my class. Basically I'm doing an API that use a decorator method:

```
    def token_required(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            token = None

            if 'x-access-token' in request.headers:
                token = request.headers['x-access-token']

            if not token:
                return jsonify({'message' : 'Token is missing!'}), 401

            try:
                data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
                current_usuario = Usuarios.query.filter_by(usuarioid = data['usuarioid']).first()
            except:
                return jsonify({'message' : 'Token is invalid!'}), 401

            return f(current_usuario, *args, **kwargs)

        return decorated
```

The problem is that I need to get the current_usuario back at my methods of the UsuariosView class, this is what I'm trying right now:

```
    class UsuariosView(MethodView):

        @token_required
        def get(self, current_usuario, usuario_id = None):

            if not current_usuario.admin:
                return ({'message' : 'Not admin!'})
            #do stuff
```

I'm not getting the current_usuario back, so I can't access the attribute admin of him and get the following error:

AttributeError: 'UsuariosView' object has no attribute 'admin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will split this up into, 1) why your code fails, 2) a terrible hack solution that should solve your immediate problem and why it will create future problems, 3) a different approach that splits up responsibilities but might not work as I don't know the specifics of your design.

1 - as it is, your decorator gets a value for `current_usuario` and binds it to the first argument of the method you call. When the method is called, all the other arguments get assigned afterwards.  Here's a clearer example of what's going on.

```
from functools import wraps


def assign_first(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff
        first_argument = 10
        return func(first_argument, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


class MyClass(object):
    @assign_first
    def first_method(self, first, second):
        print(f"self: {self}")
        print(f"first: {first}")
        print(f"second: {second}")
```

output:

```
>>> MyClass().first_method(100)
self: 10
first: <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7fdbdebd3400>
second: 100
```

The decorator binds `10` to the first argument of the method (which is `self`) and so the instance (which should be bound to `self`) now gets bound to the second argument (called `first`). You are getting that error message because your `UserView` object is getting bound to `current_usuario`, and does not have an `admin` attribute.

2) in your case, you could do the very buggy idea of having your wrapper bind to a keyword argument.  But then you would need all decorated methods to know that they need that specific keyword argument and to only use keyword arguments.

```
def assign_my_kwarg(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff
        return func(*args, my_kwarg=3, **kwargs)
    return new_func


class MyClass(object):  
    @assign_my_kwarg
    def second_method(self, *, my_kwarg, second=1):  # a function that only takes keyword arguments
        print(f"self: {self}")
        print(f"my_kwarg: {my_kwarg}")
        print(f"second: {second}")
```

running:

```
>>> MyClass().second_method(second=5)
self: <__main__.MyClass object at 0x7f679eccd400>
my_kwarg: 3
second: 5
```

So you could do the same thing with your `token_required`, returning `return f(*args, current_usuario=current_usuario, **kwargs)` and change your method signature to: `def get(self, *, current_usuario, usuario_id = None):`. But it would be super fragile and very confusing.  Anyone who calls the method and puts in `current_usuario` will cause an error because it is already assigned.  Any mis-spelling of the keyword will cause errors.  Changing the name of the keyword will cause endless headaches.

3) The real issue is that `token_required` is both checking tokens **and** getting the current user.  You can side-step this by having a function to get current user that raises custom token errors and then a decorator to handle those errors.

```
from functools import wraps


class BadTokenError(ValueError): 
    pass


class MissingTokenError(ValueError): 
    pass


def get_current_user():
    token = get_token()
    try:
        data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        return Usuarios.query.filter_by(usuarioid=data['usuarioid']).first()
    except (SPECIFIC_ERROR, OTHER_SPECIFIC_ERROR):  # do not catch MissingTokenError
        msg = 'bad token'
        raise BadTokenError(msg)


def get_token():
    try:
        token_name = 'x-access-token'
        return request.headers[token_name]
    except KeyError:
        msg = 'missing token'
        raise MissingTokenError(msg)


def catch_token_errors(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def func_with_handler(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except (BadTokenError, MissingTokenError) as error:
            return jsonify({'message': error.args[0]}), 401
    return func_with_handler


class UsuariosView(MethodView):

    @catch_token_errors
    def get(self, usuario_id=None):
        current_usuario = get_current_user()
        if not current_usuario.admin:
            return ({'message': 'Not admin!'})
```

This splits up responsibilities a little more, but may not work for what you need.